# Is there a dictionary functionality in R

Tags: r, dictionary

Is there a way to create a "dictionary" in R, such that it has  pairs?
Something to the effect of:

```
x=dictionary(c("Hi","Why","water") , c(1,5,4))
x["Why"]=5
```

I'm asking this because I am actually looking for a two categorial variables function.

So that if x=dictionary(c("a","b"),c(5,2))

```
     x  val
1    a  5 
2    b  2
```

I want to compute x1^2+x2 on all combinations of x keys

```
     x1 x2 val1  val2  x1^2+x2
1    a  a   5     5      30
2    b  a   2     5      9
3    a  b   5     2      27
4    b  b   2     2      6
```

And then I want to be able to retrieve the result using x1 and x2. Something to the effect of:
get_result["b","a"] = 9

what is the best, efficient way to do this?

Comment: would a data.frame not be enough for your task? what's the reason for needing a dictionary?

Comment: There's a pretty good solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17504356/2391771

Answer (score 68):

I know three R packages for dictionaries: `hash`, `hashmap`, and `dict`.

***Update July 2018:*** a new one, [`container`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/container/vignettes/overview.html).

***Update September 2018:*** a new one, [collections](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/collections/index.html)

### hash

Keys must be character strings. A value can be any R object.

```
library(hash)
## hash-2.2.6 provided by Decision Patterns
h <- hash() 
# set values
h[["1"]] <- 42
h[["foo"]] <- "bar"
h[["4"]] <- list(a=1, b=2)
# get values
h[["1"]]
## [1] 42
h[["4"]]
## $a
## [1] 1
## 
## $b
## [1] 2
h[c("1", "foo")]
## <hash> containing 2 key-value pair(s).
##   1 : 42
##   foo : bar
h[["key not here"]]
## NULL
```

To get keys:

```
keys(h)
## [1] "1"   "4"   "foo"
```

To get values:

```
values(h)
## $`1`
## [1] 42
## 
## $`4`
## $`4`$a
## [1] 1
## 
## $`4`$b
## [1] 2
## 
## 
## $foo
## [1] "bar"
```

The `print` instance:

```
h
## <hash> containing 3 key-value pair(s).
##   1 : 42
##   4 : 1 2
##   foo : bar
```

The `values` function accepts the arguments of `sapply`:

```
values(h, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
## [[1]]
## [1] 42
## 
## [[2]]
## [[2]]$a
## [1] 1
## 
## [[2]]$b
## [1] 2
## 
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "bar"
values(h, keys="4")
##   4
## a 1
## b 2
values(h, keys="4", simplify=FALSE)
## $`4`
## $`4`$a
## [1] 1
## 
## $`4`$b
## [1] 2
```

### hashmap

See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hashmap/README.html.

`hashmap` does *not* offer the flexibility to store arbitrary types of objects.

Keys and values are restricted to "scalar" objects (length-one character, numeric, etc.). The values must be of the same type.

```
library(hashmap)
H <- hashmap(c("a", "b"), rnorm(2))
H[["a"]]
## [1] 0.1549271
H[[c("a","b")]]
## [1]  0.1549271 -0.1222048
H[[1]] <- 9
```

Beautiful `print` instance:

```
H
## ## (character) => (numeric)  
## ##         [1] => [+9.000000]
## ##         [b] => [-0.122205]
## ##         [a] => [+0.154927]
```

Errors:

```
H[[2]] <- "Z"
## Error in x$`[[<-`(i, value): Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].
H[[2]] <- c(1,3)
## Warning in x$`[[<-`(i, value): length(keys) != length(values)!
```

### dict

Currently available only on Github: https://github.com/mkuhn/dict

**Strengths**: *arbitrary* keys and values, and fast.

```
library(dict)
d <- dict()
d[[1]] <- 42
d[[c(2, 3)]] <- "Hello!" # c(2,3) is the key
d[["foo"]] <- "bar"
d[[4]] <- list(a=1, b=2)
d[[1]]
## [1] 42
d[[c(2, 3)]]
## [1] "Hello!"
d[[4]]
## $a
## [1] 1
## 
## $b
## [1] 2
```

Accessing to a non-existing key throws an error:

```
d[["not here"]]
## Error in d$get_or_stop(key): Key error: [1] "not here"
```

But there is a nice feature to deal with that:

```
d$get("not here", "default value for missing key")
## [1] "default value for missing key"
```

Get keys:

```
d$keys()
## [[1]]
## [1] 4
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 1
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 2 3
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "foo"
```

Get values:

```
d$values()
## [[1]]
## [1] 42
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "Hello!"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "bar"
## 
## [[4]]
## [[4]]$a
## [1] 1
## 
## [[4]]$b
## [1] 2
```

Get items:

```
d$items()
## [[1]]
## [[1]]$key
## [1] 4
## 
## [[1]]$value
## [[1]]$value$a
## [1] 1
## 
## [[1]]$value$b
## [1] 2
## 
## 
## 
## [[2]]
## [[2]]$key
## [1] 1
## 
## [[2]]$value
## [1] 42
## 
## 
## [[3]]
## [[3]]$key
## [1] 2 3
## 
## [[3]]$value
## [1] "Hello!"
## 
## 
## [[4]]
## [[4]]$key
## [1] "foo"
## 
## [[4]]$value
## [1] "bar"
```

No `print` instance.

The package also provides the function `numvecdict` to deal with a dictionary in which numbers and strings (including vectors of each) can be used as keys, and that can only store vectors of numbers.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with [hatmatrix's lists, matrices, etc. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7820032/1048186)?  If lists have the same performance as these solutions, they seem like they would be the most universally-recognized way to go.

Comment: From [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34233870/1048186), it appears that R environments may be faster than both lists and hashes (for random non-vectorized access).

Comment: this is a sad state of affairs in the language; also thank you @stephanelaurent for your very thorough post (and other misc blog posts on R)

Comment: Is `dict` the only one that support multiple keys up until now?

Answer (score 34):

You simply create a vector with your key value pairs.

```r
animal_sounds <- c(
  'cat' = 'meow',
  'dog' = 'woof',
  'cow' = 'moo'
)
```

```r
print(animal_sounds['cat'])
# 'meow'
```

Update: To answer the 2nd portion of the question, you can create a dataframe and compute the values like this:

```r
val1 <- c(5,2,5,2) # Create val1 column
val2 <- c(5,5,2,2) # Create val2 column
df <- data.frame(val1, val2) # create dataframe variable
df['x1^2+x2'] <- val1^2 + val2 # create expression column
```

Output:

```
  val1 val2 x1^2+x2
1    5    5      30
2    2    5       9
3    5    2      27
4    2    2       6
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30756118)

Comment: if you use a named list instead of a named vector you can get nesting; e.g.: `dict <- list(cat = 'meow', canine = list(dog = 'bark', wolf = 'howl'))`. Dog can be indexed with `dict$canine$dog`. It's not super pretty but neither is r

Comment: @FKayani it answers the first part of the question. The question about computation of x1^2+x2 isn't.

Comment: @FKayani I edited the post to answer the 2nd portion of the question back in Jan. but adding this comment here in Dec since I'm looking back at some old posts i answered. :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use just `data.frame` and `row.names` to do this:

```
x=data.frame(row.names=c("Hi","Why","water") , val=c(1,5,4))
x["Why",]
[1] 5
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this allows you to have nested dictionaries (which is a useful aspect of dictionaries)

Answer (score 7):

In that vectors, matrices, lists, etc. behave as "dictionaries" in R, you can do something like the following:

```
> (x <- structure(c(5,2),names=c("a","b"))) ## "dictionary"
a b 
5 2 
> (result <- outer(x,x,function(x1,x2) x1^2+x2))
   a  b
a 30 27
b  9  6
> result["b","a"]
[1] 9
```

If you wanted a table as you've shown in your example, just reshape your array...

```
> library(reshape)
> (dfr <- melt(result,varnames=c("x1","x2")))
  x1 x2 value
1  a  a    30
2  b  a     9
3  a  b    27
4  b  b     6
> transform(dfr,val1=x[x1],val2=x[x2])
  x1 x2 value val1 val2
1  a  a    30    5    5
2  b  a     9    2    5
3  a  b    27    5    2
4  b  b     6    2    2
```

Comment: Parentheses around the assignment expressions are there just to print the results.

Answer (score 1):

See my [answer to a very recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804816/how-to-create-a-dictionary-hash-table-by-iterating-through-a-column/7805180#7805180). In essence, you use environments for this type of functionality.

For the higher dimensional case, you may be better off using an `array` (twodimensional) if you want the easy syntax for retrieving the result (you can name the rows and columns). As an alternative,you can `paste` together the two keys with a separator that doesn't occur in them, and then use that as a unique identifier.

To be specific, something like this:

```
tmp<-data.frame(x=c("a", "b"), val=c(5,2))
tmp2<-outer(seq(nrow(tmp)), seq(nrow(tmp)), function(lhs, rhs){tmp$val[lhs] + tmp$val[rhs]})
dimnames(tmp2)<-list(tmp$x, tmp$x)
tmp2
tmp2["a", "b"]
```

Answer (score -4):

### Using `tidyverse`

Adding an answer using more recent `tidyverse` approaches.

There are probably cleaner ways of handling the `crossing` (which creates all combinations) and `unnest`ing, but this is a quick and dirty approach.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_tbl <- tibble(x = c("A", "B"), val=c(5,2)) %>% 
  crossing(x1 = ., x2 = .) %>%  # Create all combinations
  unnest_wider(everything(), names_sep="_") %>% # Unpack into distinct columns
  mutate(result = x1_val^2 + x2_val)  # Calculate result

# Access result by accessing the row in the data frame
my_tbl %>% 
  filter(x1_x == "A", x2_x == "B") %>% 
  pull(result)
#> [1] 27

# Convert tibble to a named vector that could be accessed more easily.
# However, this is limited to string names.
my_named_vector <- my_tbl %>% 
  transmute(name = str_c(x1_x, "_", x2_x), value=result) %>% 
  deframe()

my_named_vector[["A_B"]]
#> [1] 27
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`tibble` version 3.1.6 
`dplyr` version 1.0.8 
`tidyr` version 1.2.0 
`stringr` version 1.4.0