# how to create a list in R from two vectors (one would be the keys, the other the values)?

Tags: r

I have two vectors and I want to create a list in R where one vector are the keys and the other the values. I thought that I was going to find easily the answer in my books or googleing around and I was expecting to find a solution like when adding names to a vector ( names(v)<- names_vector), but I failed.

I have come myself with two possible solutions but none of them seems elegant to me. R is not my main programming language but I assume that being R so pragmatic a better solution should exist (something like list(keys=x, values=y)).

My solution 1: the classical loop solution:

```
    > xx <- 1:3
    > yy <- letters1:3
    > zz =list()
    >for(i in 1:length(yy)) {zz[[yy[i]]]<-xx[i]}
```

my solution 2: indirect path through named vectors:

```
    > names(xx) <- letters[1:3]
    > as.list(xx)
```

Seems that I have a solution, but my vectors have 1 million or more elements  and I am worried not only about coding style (important to me) but also about efficiency (but I don't know how to do profiling in R). Is there a more appropriate way of doing this? Is it a good practice to use the named vector shortcut?

[[UPDATE]] my applogies, probably I oversimplify the question to make it reproducible. I wanted to give names to the elements of a list. I tried names() first but seems that I did something wrong and did not work. So I got the wrong idea that names() does not work with lists. But they indeed do as shown by the accepted answer

Comment: You said  "1 million or more elements (that are large objects)" ? can you precise the structure of your object to get an idea how large is it?

Comment: @agstudy I took that to mean the OP is describing the vectors as large objects due to the number of elements, not the elements themselves as large objects? Still, to combine two vectors in a list.......

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If your values are all scalars, then there's nothing wrong with having a "key-value store" that's just a vector.

```
vals <- 1:1000000
keys <- paste0("key", 1:1000000)
names(vals) <- keys
```

You can then retrieve the value corresponding to a given key with

```
vals["key42"]
[1] 42
```

IIRC R uses hashing for character-based indexing, so lookups should be fast regardless of the size of your vector.

If your values can be arbitrary objects, then you do need a list.

```
vals <- list(1:100, lm(speed ~ dist, data=cars), function(x) x^2)
names(vals) <- c("numbers", "model", "function")

sq <- vals[["function"]]
sq(5)
[1] 25
```

<s>If your question is about *constructing* the list, I wouldn't be too worried. R internally is copy-on-write (objects are only copied if their contents are modified), so doing something like</s>

```
vals <- list(1:1000000, 1:1000000, <other big objects>)
```

will not actually make extra copies of everything.

Edit: I just checked, and R *will* copy everything if you do `lst <- list(....)`. Go figure. So if you're already close to the memory limit on your machine, this won't work. On the other hand, if you do `names(lst) <- ....`, it *won't* make another copy of `lst`. Go figure again.

Comment: +1 I accept this answers over SimmonO101 only because is a bit more elaborate but essentially both are the good answers. As I have put in my updated question, I got the wrong impression that names() was not working with lists so I tried to find other options. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

It can be done in one statement using `setNames`:

```
xx <- 1:3
yy <- letters[1:3]
```

To create a named list:

```
as.list(setNames(xx, yy))
# $a
# [1] 1
# 
# $b
# [1] 2
# 
# $c
# [1] 3
```

Or a named vector:

```
setNames(xx, yy)
# a b c 
# 1 2 3
```

In the case of the list, this is programmatically equivalent to your "named vector" approach but maybe a little more elegant.

---

Here are some benchmarks that show the two approaches are just as fast. Also note that the order of operations is very important in avoiding an unnecessary and costly copy of the data:

```
f1 <- function(xx, yy) {
  names(xx) <- yy
  as.list(xx)
}

f2 <- function(xx, yy) {
  out <- as.list(xx)
  names(out) <- yy
  out
}

f3 <- function(xx, yy) as.list(setNames(xx, yy))
f4 <- function(xx, yy) setNames(as.list(xx), yy)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  f1(xx, yy),
  f2(xx, yy),
  f3(xx, yy),
  f4(xx, yy)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#        expr    min      lq  median      uq     max neval
#  f1(xx, yy) 41.207 42.6390 43.2885 45.7340 114.853   100
#  f2(xx, yy) 39.187 40.3525 41.5330 43.7435 107.130   100
#  f3(xx, yy) 39.280 41.2900 42.1450 43.8085 109.017   100
#  f4(xx, yy) 76.278 78.1340 79.1450 80.7525 180.825   100
```

Answer (score 5):

Another serious option here , is to use `data.table`. Which use the key to sort your structure and it is very fast to access elements specially when you have a large numbers . Here an example:

```
library(data.table)   
DT <- data.table(xx = 1:1e6, 
             k = paste0("key", 1:1e6),key="k")
```

Dt is a data.table with 2 columns , where I set the column k as a key.
     DT
                 xx         k
          1:      1      key1
          2:     10     key10
          3:    100    key100
          4:   1000   key1000
          5:  10000  key10000
         ---
     999996: 999995 key999995
     999997: 999996 key999996
     999998: 999997 key999997
     999999: 999998 key999998
    1000000: 999999 key999999

Now I can access my data.table using the key like this:

```
DT['key1000']
         k   xx
1: key1000 1000
```

Here a benchmarking comparing the data.table solution to a named vector:

```
vals <- 1:1000000
DT <- data.table(xx = vals ,
                 k = paste0("key", vals),key="k")
keys <- paste0("key", vals)
names(vals) <- keys
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark( vals["key42"],DT["key42"],times=100)

Unit: microseconds
          expr        min          lq     median         uq        max neval
 vals["key42"] 111938.692 113207.4945 114924.010 130010.832 361077.210   100
   DT["key42"]    768.753    797.0085   1055.661   1067.987   2058.985   100
```

Comment: +1 data.table is one of these useful packages that I have always nearby but never have the time to learn it in order to use it in production.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean to do this?...

```
xx <- 1:3
yy <- letters[1:3]
zz <- list( xx , yy )
names(zz) <- c("keys" , "values")
zz
#$keys
#[1] 1 2 3

#$values
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

AFAIK this is the canonical way of making a list of vectors. I am happy to be corrected. If you are new to R, I'd advise it is *generally* unwise to use a `for` loop because there are *usually* vectorised methods to accomplish *most* tasks that are more efficient and faster.

Comment: more or less (not using this names for the names but a vector of keys ;-)). I wanted the content of a vector become the names of the content of a list. Names() was the first thing that I tried and I can not remember why, it did not work (probably I did something wrong) and I got the wrong idea that names() was only for vectors. I know about the loops performance and this is the reason why I was asking, but thanks anyway for doublechecking.

Answer (score 0):

Hong's output is wrong.

Should use vals[["key42"]]

```
> vals[["key42"]]
[1] 42

vals <- 1:1000000
keys <- paste0("key", 1:1000000)
names(vals) <- keys

vals["key42"]
key42
   42
```