# R: Vector of keys and vector of values to list

Tags: r

Suppose I have two vectors as follows:

```
keys <- c("key1", "key2", "key3")
values <- c(1,2,3)
```

and I want to produce a list like this:

```
list("key1" = 1, "key2" = 2, "key3" = 3)
```

What's a good way to do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can perform the operation in a single line with base R

```
as.list(setNames(values, keys))

#$key1
#[1] 1

#$key2
#[1] 2

#$key3
#[1] 3
```

Comment: I have since found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504241/how-to-create-a-list-in-r-from-two-vectors-one-would-be-the-keys-the-other-the

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
keys <- c("key1", "key2", "key3")
values <- c(1,2,3)

my_list <- as.list(values) %>% setNames(keys)
```

Comment: `L <- as.list(values); names(L) <- keys` with base R. The operator `%>%` is not in base R.

Comment: @RonakShah Thinking about it, that's perhaps the most intuitive solution - do you want to add it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` too:

```
x <- split(values, keys)
```

The side effect is that the resulting list will be sorted by keys.

Comment: Thanks, I figured there must be a simpler/builtin way of doing it.  I've used split before, but it didn't occur to me to use it in this case, despite it being pretty much `split`'s simplest use case!

Comment: I have to mention that split will change the order of the key-value pairs. It is only simple. Personally, I prefer `as.list` -> `names <-` approach.