# data.table and hash -- speed and flexibility to handle multiple values per key

Tags: r, hash, data.table

I have 2 questions:

1. Is `hash` faster than `data.table` for Big Data?
2. How can I deal with multiple values per key, if I want to use a hash-based approach?

I looked at the vignette of the related packages and Googled some potential solutions, but I'm still not sure about the answers to the questions above.

Considering the following post,

[R fast single item lookup from list vs data.table vs hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232865/r-fast-single-item-lookup-from-list-vs-data-table-vs-hash)

it seems that a single lookup in a `data.table` object is actually quite slow, even slower than in a list in Base R?

However a lookup using a hash object from `hash` is very speedy, based on this benchmark -- is that accurate?

However, it looks like the object hash is handling only unique keys?

In the following only 2 (key,value) pairs are created.

```
library(hash)
> h <- hash(c("A","B","A"),c(1,2,3))
> h
<hash> containing 2 key-value pair(s).
  A : 3
  B : 2
```

So, if i have a table with (key,values) where a key can have different values, and i want to do a (quick) lookup for the values corresponding to this key, what is the best object/data structure in R to do that ?

Can we still use the `hash` object or is `data.table` the most appropriate in this case ?

Let's say we are in the context of dealing a problem with very large tables, otherwise this discussion is irrelevant.

Related link:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/hash-table-performance-in-r-part-i/

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to the question in the SO post that you refer to, not the answer.

As you'll see in the answer there, the results you get from the benchmark can change a lot depending on how you utilize `data.table`, or any given big data package.

You are correct that with the simplest implementation of `hash()` each key has 1 value. There are, of course, work-arounds for this. One would be to have a value which is a string and append the string with your multiple values:

```
h <- hash(c("Key 1","Key 2","Key 3"),c("1","2","1 and 2"))
h
<hash> containing 3 key-value pair(s).
  Key 1 : 1
  Key 2 : 2
  Key 3 : 1 and 2
```

Another map be to use a [hash table](http://www.r-bloggers.com/hash-table-performance-in-r-part-iiiin-part-iof-this-series-i-explained-how-r-hashed/) via a hashed environment in R, or perhaps via `hashmap()`.

I do not know that there is a single, definitive proof that `hash` or `data.table` will always be faster. It could always vary by your use case, data, and how you implement them in your code.

In general, I'd say that `data.table` might be a more common solution if your use case does not involve a true key-value pair, and no work-around would be needed to address the issue of multiple values per key.

Comment: @FaguiCurtain No problem! :)