# Tidyverse way of repeatedly following parent IDs until ancestor

Tags: r, recursion, tree, tidyverse

[The themes dataset from Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/downloads/) includes for each theme its ID and its parent's ID (columns have been renamed here), which may recurse (ID may have grandparents, great-grandparents, etc.) Here is an example which follows the parent chain City -> Advent -> Seasonal:

```
themes <- data.frame(theme_id = c(206, 207, 208), 
                     theme_name = c("Seasonal", "Advent", "City"), 
                     parent_theme_id = c(NA, 206, 207))
```

Here is my base R code to follow the parent IDs up until reaching NA, meaning no parent:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(themes)) {
  orig_id <- themes[i,]$theme_id
  cur_id <- orig_id
  repeat {
    par_id <- themes[themes$theme_id == cur_id,]$parent_theme_id
    if (is.na(par_id)) break
    cur_id <- par_id
  }
 
  themes[themes$theme_id == orig_id,]$ancestor_theme_id = cur_id
}
```

Is there a nicer tidyverse or base R way of creating a new column that consists of the greatest ancestor IDs? I can't think of a nice way to recursively follow ID "pointers" without operating one row at a time and having a loop somewhere.

Comment: Sorry but I do not exactly understand what you want. Maybe you could explain in detail?

Comment: I don't know of an easy tidyverse way to do things, possibly because open recursion like that (in the hands of unaware users) can run amuck rather easily (and, since R doesn't do tail-recursion efficiently, it uses stack-space rather inefficiently).

Comment: @r2evans there are no loops or missing IDs, if it helps

Comment: I'm not saying that recursion in this example is problematic, I'm saying that I do not know of any standard functions in dplyr/tidyr/purrr that deal with recursive processing, likely because it's easy to get into a bad mess using recursion incorrectly. (Loops are a different story of recursion pain.) I suspect that you can do something a little more frame-friendly by repeatedly `left_join`ing it on itself until all RHS-`theme_id` (joined in) are `NA`.

Comment: @r2evans I actually originally tried left_join with itself before I realized parents could recurse. If ancestors only goes up to grandparents then I would only need two joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @r2evans explains in the comments, there aren't tidyverse functions for the recursive lookup itself, but you can make your code a bit more succinct and tidyverse-y by defining a recursive function and calling it from `mutate(map_dbl())`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

find_ancestor <- function(id) {
  dat <- cur_data()
  parent <- filter(dat, theme_id == id)$parent_theme_id
  if (is.na(parent)) id else find_ancestor(parent)
}

themes %>% 
  mutate(ancestor_theme_id = map_dbl(theme_id, find_ancestor))
```

```
  theme_id theme_name parent_theme_id ancestor_theme_id
1      206   Seasonal              NA               206
2      207     Advent             206               206
3      208       City             207               206
```

Answer (score 3):

Three methods come to mind:

1. Naive `data.table` method.
2. Memoized `data.table` method.
3. Using the `environment` object.

### 1. Naive `data.table` method

I would use `data.table` here because once you set a key, individual row lookups tend to be [twice as fast](https://appsilon.com/fast-data-lookups-in-r-dplyr-vs-data-table/) as `tidyverse`.

```r
setDT(themes)
setkey(themes, theme_id)

lookup_parent <- function(themes, id_to_lookup) {
    id_parent <- themes[theme_id == id_to_lookup, parent_theme_id]

    if (is.na(id_parent)) {
        return(id_to_lookup)
    }

    lookup_parent(themes, id_parent)
}

themes[,
    ancestor_theme_id := lookup_parent(themes, theme_id),
    by = .I
]

# Index: <theme_id>
#    theme_id theme_name parent_theme_id ancestor_theme_id
#       <num>     <char>           <num>             <num>
# 1:      206   Seasonal              NA               206
# 2:      207     Advent             206               206
# 3:      208       City             207               206
```

This is still basically going to loop over every row but it reads more nicely.

### 2. Memoized `data.table`

The above will be slow with large data or deeply nested children. A cheap and easy way to make it quicker is to use the [`memoise`](https://memoise.r-lib.org/) package to cache previous lookups, so we don't have to recurse all the way to the parent each time.

```r
library(memoise)
lookup_parent_m <- memoise(lookup_parent)

themes[,
    ancestor_theme_id := lookup_parent_m(themes, theme_id),
    by = .I
]
```

Although `data.table` is faster than `tidyverse`, both are relatively slow for these kinds of operations compared to hashing or the built-in [environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232865/r-fast-single-item-lookup-from-list-vs-data-table-vs-hash) object. From the benchmarks in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34233870/12545041) you can see several alternatives are considerably faster than `data.table`:

```
Unit: microseconds
                  expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
      lookup_hash[[x]]   10.767   12.9070   22.67245   23.2915   26.1710   68.654   100
 test_lookup_list[[x]]  847.700  853.2545  887.55680  863.0060  893.8925 1369.395   100
     test_lookup_dt[x] 2652.023 2711.9405 2771.06400 2758.8310 2803.9945 3373.273   100
  test_lookup_env[[x]]    1.588    1.9450    4.61595    2.5255    6.6430   27.977   100
```

### 3. Using the `environment` object

This is relatively straightforward to do. However, there is a fixed cost of creating the environment, which takes no time at all with the example data but may be noticeable with your real data.

```r
lookup_list <- list()

lookup_list[as.character(
    themes$theme_id
)] <- themes$parent_theme_id

lookup_env <- list2env(lookup_list)

lookup_parent_in_env <- function(id, env = lookup_env) {
    id_parent <- env[[as.character(id)]]

    if (is.na(id_parent)) {
        return(id)
    }

    lookup_parent_in_env(id_parent, env)
}

# Let's memoise for good measure
lookup_parent_in_env_m  <- memoise(lookup_parent_in_env)

themes$parent_theme_id  <- sapply(
    themes$theme_id, 
    lookup_parent_in_env_m
)

themes

#   theme_id theme_name parent_theme_id
# 1      206   Seasonal             206
# 2      207     Advent             206
# 3      208       City             206
```

This is not a common pattern so it does sacrifice some readability, but I imagine it will be significantly faster than the `data.table` option.

Comment: I've never used data.table but this looks easier to do rowwise operations

Comment: Nice use of memoise!

Comment: @thanks! Looking at your answer I wonder if my second logical test is necessary - I thought that a theme could have its own ID as a parent, but actually that makes no sense, so your function is a little more concise.

Comment: yes, a theme will never have itself as a parent

Comment: by the way the dataframe is small enough so that performance is not a concern

Comment: @qwr OK I've taken out the second logical condition. Re performance, then I would just use whichever of these is most readable. Row-wise lookups scale terribly in R though so I enjoy thinking about performance with these kinds of questions even if it's not an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

this can get complex pretty fast when there are many connections/ multiple parents for a single node.
If so, you could give this `igraph`-approach a try

```
mydata <- data.frame(theme_id = c(206, 207, 208, 208, 207, 301, 302), 
                     parent_theme_id = c(NA, 206, 207, 209, 210, NA, 301))

library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

verts <- unique(as.vector(as.matrix(mydata)))
edges <- mydata %>% select(parent_theme_id, theme_id) %>% drop_na()
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = TRUE, vertices = verts[!is.na(verts)])
plot(g)
```

This results in the following graph.
The 'parents' from each node are the starting-points of the graph (follow the arrows from each node upstream to find them).
[image]

```
# get startpoints (which are endpoints in your case)
startpoints <- names(V(g)[degree(g, mode = 'out') > 0 & degree(g, mode = 'in') == 0])
#[1] "206" "301" "209" "210"

#calculate all paths from all startpoints
l <- unlist(lapply(startpoints , function(x) all_simple_paths(g, from=x)), recursive = FALSE)
# get the nodes involved.. the first node is the 'parent'/starting point
ans <- lapply(seq.int(l), function(i) as_ids(l[[i]]))
# [[1]]
# [1] "206" "207"
# [[2]]
# [1] "206" "207" "208"
# [[3]]
# [1] "301" "302"
# [[4]]
# [1] "209" "208"
# [[5]]
# [1] "210" "207"
# [[6]]
# [1] "210" "207" "208"

unique(
  bind_rows(
    lapply(ans, function(x) data.frame(parent = x[1], child = x[2:length(x)]))
  ))

#   parent child
# 1    206   207
# 3    206   208
# 4    301   302
# 5    209   208
# 6    210   207
# 8    210   208
```

This information, you can join back into your original data