# Check monotonically increasing per row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe as the following :

```
   COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     1     1     1     1     1     2
 3     1     1     1     1     1     3
 4     1     1     1     1     1     4
 5     1     2     1     1     1     5
 6     1     1     1     1     1     6
 7     1     3     4     5     6     7
 8     1     1     1     1     1     8
 9     1     1     9     1     1     9
10     1     3     5     7     9    10
```

I'd like to filter this dataset to keep only values from `COL_1` to `COL_6` strictly increasing, so it would be as the following:

```
   COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 7     1     3     4     5     6     7
10     1     3     5     7     9    10
```

EDIT : The code should be used in a function with a dynamic number of columns (which will be named from `COL_1` to `COL_N`). A "basic" code such as

```
df %>% filter(COL_6 > COL_5 & ... & COL_2 > COL_1)
```

will not work in my situation. Thank you very much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With a bit of work, you could use Reduce for this. For example

```
keep <- Reduce(function(x, y) {
  list(y, x[[2]] & (x[[1]] < y))
}, dd, init=list(dd[[1]]-1, TRUE))[[2]]
which(keep)
# [1]  7 10
dd[keep, ]
#    COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
# 7      1     3     4     5     6     7
# 10     1     3     5     7     9    10
```

Tested with

```
dd <- read.table(text="
COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2     1     1     1     1     1     2
3     1     1     1     1     1     3
4     1     1     1     1     1     4
5     1     2     1     1     1     5
6     1     1     1     1     1     6
7     1     3     4     5     6     7
8     1     1     1     1     1     8
9     1     1     9     1     1     9
10     1     3     5     7     9    10", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 14):

##### Method 1: `apply` by rows

```r
df[!colSums(apply(df, 1, diff) <= 0), ]

#    COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
# 7      1     3     4     5     6     7
# 10     1     3     5     7     9    10
```

The trick is that: `!` + numeric vector will convert non-zeros to `FALSE` and zeros to `TRUE`.

```r
!(-3:3)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

##### Method 2: `Map`+`Reduce` (Much Faster)

```r
df[Reduce(`&`, Map(`>`, df[-1], df[-ncol(df)])), ]
```

---

##### Benchmark on a larger dataset

```r
library(microbenchmark)

bm <- microbenchmark(
  MrFlick = df[Reduce(\(x, y) { list(y, x[[2]] & (x[[1]] < y)) }, df, init = list(df[[1]]-1, TRUE))[[2]], ],
  Darren_2 = df[Reduce(`&`, Map(`>`, df[-1], df[-ncol(df)])), ],
  LMc = df[lapply(df, increasing())[[length(df)]], ],
  Thomas_2 = df[rowSums(df[-1] > df[-ncol(df)]) == ncol(df) - 1, ],
  Thomas_1 = df[rowMeans(df[-1] > df[-ncol(df)]) == 1, ],
  zx8754_1 = df[ apply(df, 1, \(i) !is.unsorted(i, strictly = TRUE)), ],
  Darren_1 = df[!colSums(apply(df, 1, diff) <= 0), ],
  zx8754_2 = df[ apply(df, 1, \(i) all(rank(i) == seq.int(ncol(df)))), ],
  setup = {
    nr <- 1e4
    df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1e6, 0, 100), nr, 1e2))
    # pick 100 rows to sort
    ind <- sample(1:nr, 100)
    df[ind, ] <- t(apply(df[ind, ], 1, sort))
  },
  unit = "relative"
)

# Unit: relative
#      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#   MrFlick  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.0000000   100
#  Darren_2  1.106325  1.094651  1.076697  1.087586  1.005100 1.4959953   100
#       LMc  1.343194  1.341192  1.250389  1.331452  1.154049 0.9628282   100
#  Thomas_2  1.582195  1.572858  1.521608  1.574595  1.382800 1.3160589   100
#  Thomas_1  1.580272  1.563802  1.375415  1.552095  1.301315 1.1092026   100
#  zx8754_1  6.116539  6.362767  5.427589  6.896683  4.752581 2.2093543   100
#  Darren_1 23.723654 25.009280 20.208686 25.972528 19.187991 4.9937860   100
#  zx8754_2 44.612050 46.052300 34.288879 45.622591 29.601381 7.9472758   100
```

[image]

Comment: impressive benchmarking, +1 already! I found that `ncol` is faster than `length`, so I updated my solution :P

Answer (score 5):

Here is a fast solution that uses little memory (using `bench::mark`) by leveraging R environments. When you create a function it is bound to its current environment. This has two advantages:

1. Environments are one of the [fastest ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34232865/6382434) to look up a value.
2. The bound environment provides "memory" in the sense that you can save state information, such as values from a previous iteration. This is efficient here so you don't need to iterate more than once.

We can leverage this by creating a function factory (a function that outputs a function):

```r
increasing <- function() {
  prev <- is_incr <- NULL
  function(cur) {
    is_incr <<- if (is.null(prev)) rep(T, length(cur)) else (cur > prev) & is_incr
    prev <<- cur
    return(is_incr)
  }
}

df[lapply(df, increasing())[[length(df)]],]
```

Note - if you bind the "manufactured" function to a name, since information persists in the environment you would need to be re-assign the function before being calling its bound name again.

---

The tidyverse offers a (in my opinion) more readable solution using `rowwise`, if speed is not a concern:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  rowwise() |>
  filter(all(diff(c_across(starts_with('COL'))) > 0)) |>
  ungroup()
```

**Output**

```
  COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     3     4     5     6     7
2     1     3     5     7     9    10
```

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(COL_1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), COL_2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L), COL_3 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 5L), COL_4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 7L), COL_5 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 9L), COL_6 = 1:10), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Answer (score 5):

One base R approach

```
df[colSums(apply(df,1,diff)>0)==ncol(df)-1,]

   COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
7      1     3     4     5     6     7
10     1     3     5     7     9    10
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the following base R options

- `rowMeans`

```
> df[rowMeans(df[-1] - df[-ncol(df)] > 0) == 1, ]
   COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
7      1     3     4     5     6     7
10     1     3     5     7     9    10
```

- `rowSums`

```
> df[rowSums(df[-1] > df[-ncol(df)]) == ncol(df) - 1, ]
   COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
7      1     3     4     5     6     7
10     1     3     5     7     9    10
```

- `NA` + `&`

```
> df[complete.cases(NA & (df[-1] <= df[-ncol(df)])), ]
   COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
7      1     3     4     5     6     7
10     1     3     5     7     9    10
```

## Benchmarking (borrowed from [@Darren Tsai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76821232/12158757))

```
bm <- microbenchmark(
    MrFlick = df[Reduce(function(x, y) {
        list(y, x[[2]] & (x[[1]] < y))
    }, df, init = list(df[[1]] - 1, TRUE))[[2]], ],
    Darren_1 = df[!colSums(apply(df, 1, diff) <= 0), ],
    Darren_2 = df[Reduce(`&`, Map(`>`, df[-1], df[-ncol(df)])), ],
    zx8754_1 = df[apply(df, 1, function(i) !is.unsorted(i, strictly = TRUE)), ],
    zx8754_2 = df[apply(df, 1, function(i) all(rank(i) == seq.int(ncol(df)))), ],
    tic1 = df[rowMeans(df[-1] > df[-ncol(df)]) == 1, ],
    tic2 = df[rowSums(df[-1] > df[-ncol(df)]) == ncol(df) - 1, ],
    tic3 = df[complete.cases(NA & (df[-1] <= df[-ncol(df)])), ],
    setup = {
        df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1e6, 0, 100), 1e4, 1e2))
        ind <- sample(1:1e4, 1e2)
        df[ind, ] <- t(apply(df[ind, ], 1, sort))
    },
    times = 10L,
    unit = "relative"
)
```

which gives

```
> bm
Unit: relative
     expr        min         lq      mean    median         uq        max neval
  MrFlick  0.9080191  0.9144448  1.028867  1.127537  1.0952573  1.0503769    10
 Darren_1 16.5282125 17.7915946 19.161257 19.417784 20.7691135 19.3924344    10
 Darren_2  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.0000000  1.0000000    10
 zx8754_1  4.3833846  4.5916794  4.958092  4.617921  4.1234763  9.0226479    10
 zx8754_2 27.4681979 27.4405513 25.276613 26.550560 22.5151429 24.6191662    10
     tic1  1.0823147  1.3835146  1.997294  1.511849  1.5489377  6.0274525    10
     tic2  1.0455388  1.0989379  1.016991  1.069731  0.9690896  0.9463357    10
     tic3  2.1156887  2.1455595  2.289243  2.501887  2.1517687  2.5138369    10
```

Answer (score 3):

Using *is.unsorted*, check if vector is unsorted, then negate:

```
dd[ apply(dd, 1, function(i) !is.unsorted(i, strictly = TRUE)), ]
#    COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
# 7      1     3     4     5     6     7
# 10     1     3     5     7     9    10
```

Using *rank*, check if the ranking same as 1:number of columns:

```
dd[ apply(dd, 1, function(i) all(rank(i) == seq.int(ncol(dd)))), ]
#    COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
# 7      1     3     4     5     6     7
# 10     1     3     5     7     9    10
```

Answer (score 3):

With `collapse`, you can combine the very efficient `fdiff` with `fmean` to make a vectorized solution over all columns:

```r
library(collapse)
dd[!fsum(fdiff(t(dd)) <= 0), ]
#or
dd[fmean(fdiff(t(dd)) > 0) == 1, ]

#    COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6
# 7      1     3     4     5     6     7
# 10     1     3     5     7     9    10
```

Another solution with `matrixStats`:

```r
library(matrixStats)
dd[!rowSums(rowDiffs(as.matrix(dd)) <= 0), ]
```