# Subsetting named vector/list using names, while keeping unmatched categories

Tags: r

I am trying to subset named list while keeping names to unmatched elements.

```
menu = list(
  "bacon" = "foo",
  "eggs" = "bar",
  "beans" = "baz"
  )

select = c("bacon", "eggs", "spam")

menu[select]
# $bacon
# [1] "foo"
# 
# $eggs
# [1] "bar"
# 
# $<NA>
# NULL
```

The subset has a correct length (3), reports unmatched elements as `NULL`, but their name is reported as `<NA>`

Is there nice `base` how to keep names of this list? The only way I found is to essentially "reset" the names using:

```
menu[select] |> setNames(select)
# $bacon
# [1] "foo"
# 
# $eggs
# [1] "bar"
# 
# $spam
# NULL
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: I don't know if you'd call it simpler, but since keeping unmatched elements isn't very standard I'd recommend creating an empty results list and then filling in the matches: `results = list(); results[select] = menu[select]`

Comment: I'm not sure how you can improve on `setNames(menu[select], select)`. Unless of course you prefer to use `\`names<-\`(menu[select], select)` ;-)

Comment: @GregorThomas Unmatched elements are already present (as demonstrated in the code), just their identity is not preserved.

Comment: @r2evans I think you are right. Should I close the question?

Would you and others consider the outcome of `setNames(menu[select], select)` as a desired default behaviour of `menu[select]` in this case?

Comment: I don't know your exact use-case, but it makes sense to me that if your output must be named in the order of `select` and it must contain the real value or `NULL`, then `setNames(..)` is likely the best base-R way to go. That's my opinion. As for this question, over to you, but I suggest you accept one and let it be.

Comment: @Colombo yes, I see that the that the unmatched elements are present in this case. I stand by my statement that "keeping unmatched elements isn't very standard" in R. If you had a data frame `mtcars[c("mpg", "wt", "foo")]` you'd get an error, not a `NULL`. (Not that my solution in comments does any better in that case...)

Comment: @r2evans please submit `setNames(menu[select], select)` as answer. I can't see any other efficient/simpler base solution.

Answer (score 4):

You want a hash table with a default value. The [fastest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232865/r-fast-single-item-lookup-from-list-vs-data-table-vs-hash) hash tables in R are environments.

```r
e <- list2env(menu)
```

Then we can subset with [`mget()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html):

```r
mget(select, envir = e, ifnotfound = list(NULL))

# $bacon
# [1] "foo"

# $eggs
# [1] "bar"

# $spam
# NULL
```

While hash tables are fast, `mget()` might be a bottleneck. If you are measuring performance you could also try the [`rlang`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/env_get.html) approach, i.e. `rlang::env_get_list(e, select, default = NULL)`, which produces the same results.

Answer (score 3):

I think your solution is good. One possibility would be to add the names to the list that are in `select` and do not have an element in `menu`:

```r
menu[setdiff(select, names(menu))] <- list(NULL)

menu[select]
# $bacon
# [1] "foo"
# 
# $eggs
# [1] "bar"
# 
# $spam
# NULL
```

Comment: Please, don't modify the original list.

Comment: @Colombo then simply make a copy of the list and you can modify that copy.

Comment: My mistake, I was misreading the second statement - I never downvoted by the way, but have an upvote now.

Answer (score 3):

We can loop and subset:

```
sapply(select, function(i) menu[[ i ]], simplify = FALSE)
# $bacon
# [1] "foo"
# 
# $eggs
# [1] "bar"
# 
# $spam
# NULL
```

Comment: This does work as intended, but it is not exactly efficient. On my PC, it is 8x slower. And `sapply` often uses automagic, which is often not ideal. For instance, if all elements are found, `sapply` returns _vector_ instead of list. This is a big no no. And I bet that if the objects in list are vectors that have the same length > 1, the returned element will be matrix. `simplify=FALSE` is a must in this case.

Comment: @Colombo you are right, added "simplify".

Answer (score 2):

Seems that there is not more elegant solution than `menu[select] |> setNames(select)` or the version suggested by @r2evans `setNames(menu[select], select)`. These are identical and differ only in the use of `|>`, in fact, the piped version is parsed to an identical form. Pick whichever you prefer, I find the piped solution a tad bit more readable, while non-piped one is tad bit more terse.

Anyway, thank you everyone for your creative input, some very creative solutions were proposed. To not make this completely useless, let's test them!

Normally, I would just use `microbenchmark`, but `bench::mark` also offers some memory performance, which will be quite useful to compare some solutions.

First, we will define data as above, and then write down each individual solution:

```
menu = list(
  "bacon" = "foo",
  "eggs" = "bar",
  "beans" = "baz"
  )

select = c("bacon", "eggs", "spam")
```

```
# the original proposed solution in the form proposed by @r2evans
f_setNames = function(x, select) setNames(x[select], select)


# sapply solution suggested by zx8754
f_sapply = function(x, select){
  sapply(select, function(i) x[[ i ]], simplify = FALSE)
  }

# modifying the original list by LMc
f_modify = function(x, select){
  x[setdiff(select, names(x))] = list(NULL)
  x[select]
  }

# converting to environment by SamR
f_env = function(x, select){
  y = list2env(x)
  mget(select, envir = y, ifnotfound = list(NULL))
  }

# check that they all produce identical solution:
y = f_setNames(menu, select)
identical(y, f_sapply(menu,select))
identical(y, f_modify(menu, select))
identical(y, f_env(menu, select))

bench::mark(
  f_select = menu[select],
  f_setNames = f_setNames(menu, select),
  f_sapply = f_sapply(menu, select),
  f_modify = f_modify(menu, select),
  f_env = f_env(menu, select),
  check = FALSE
  )

#  A tibble: 5 × 13
#  expression      min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
# 1 f_select          0 1.05µs   803993.        0B      0   10000     0     12.4ms
# 2 f_setNames 488.94ns 1.96µs   438560.    5.95KB     43.9  9999     1     22.8ms
# 3 f_sapply      3.7µs 5.73µs   174192.   12.04KB     17.4  9999     1     57.4ms
# 4 f_modify     4.26µs 6.21µs   158817.   15.78KB     31.8  9998     2       63ms
# 5 f_env        2.31µs 3.84µs   256353.   11.58KB     25.6  9999     1       39ms
# ℹ 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

Strangely, the allocated memory is 0 (at least was on some runs). I think this might be because of tiny dataset size. We can fix that.

```
# random names
random_string = function(n, size = 5){
    replicate(n, sample(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9), size = size, replace=TRUE) |> paste0(collapse=""))
    }

# random data
random_ragged_list = function(n, size = 1:100, elements = 1:100){
    replicate(n, sample(elements, sample(size, 1), replace=TRUE))
    }

# let the size be this many
size = 10000 # thats 10 000

# generate random
rstr = random_string(2*size) |> unique()
rnames = rstr[seq_len(size)]
rempty = rstr[size + seq_len(size / 2)]

# generate random ragged list
menu = random_ragged_list(size) |> setNames(rnames)

# same proportion of known and unknown
select = c(sample(rnames, size = size / 2), rempty) |> sample()


bench::mark(
  f_select = menu[select],
  f_setNames = f_setNames(menu, select),
  f_sapply = f_sapply(menu, select),
  f_modify = f_modify(menu, select),
  f_env = f_env(menu, select),
  iterations = 10, # any more and my computer explodes
  filter_gc = TRUE,
  check = FALSE
  )

# # A tibble: 5 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 f_select   712.25µs 977.37µs   1106.    881.52KB    0        10     0
# 2 f_setNames 963.75µs 992.35µs   1006.    881.52KB    0        10     0
# 3 f_sapply   481.13ms 486.15ms      2.06   78.17KB    0.228     9     1
# 4 f_modify     1.49ms   1.56ms    629.      1.85MB    0        10     0
# 5 f_env        2.63ms   2.69ms    345.    250.14KB   38.3       9     1
# # ℹ 5 more variables: total_time <bch:tm>, result <list>, memory <list>,
#   time <list>, gc <list>
```

Numbers can differ on different computers. And they are all over the place.

Regarding speed, `setNames` is fastest. `modify` somehow came, which is quite surprising to me second, and `env` third. `sapply` is woefully slow. But memory changes everything. `sapply` is somehow the best performing when it comes to memory, beating simply setting attribute (`setNames`). In fact, `setNames` is being beaten by `env` as well. Only `modify` managed to be worse, since it copies and modifies the entire list.

It feels to me that `setNames` shouldn't have huge memory issues. But looks like something is happening to the list.

@SamR points out (rightfully so) that converting to hashmap / environment is an expensive operation.

A better comparison would be to compare `setNames` solution with `mget` call only. So lets rewrite `f_env` to remove the hashmap generation and convert `menu` to `menu_env` elsewhere.

```
f_env2 = function(x, select){
  mget(select, envir = x, ifnotfound = list(NULL))
  }
menu_env = list2env(menu)

bench::mark(
  f_setNames = f_setNames(menu, select),
  f_env = f_env(menu, select),
  f_env2 = f_env2(menu_env, select),
  iterations = 100,
  filter_gc = TRUE,
  check = FALSE
  )
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 f_setNames 735.16µs 899.08µs     1023.   881.5KB    10.3     99     1
# 2 f_env        2.66ms   3.08ms      314.   250.1KB     3.17    99     1
# 3 f_env2       1.52ms   1.62ms      599.    78.2KB     0      100     0
```

This makes `f_env2` 2x faster. Not as fast as `setNames`, which is still twice as fast. The memory imprint drops significantly. And again, the memory imprint of `setNames` is relatively large for some reason.

Comment: I like that you've done some benchmarks and particularly the longer one - time differences in a three item list will be negligible. I'm not sure it's fair to count the time taken converting the list to an environment. Environments are a good approach if you want to do lots of lookups from a big list. Creating the hash table is an expensive operation but only needs to be done once. The lookups themselves then tend to be quite fast. If you have lots of lists and you're doing one lookup from each one then this benchmark is appropriate and environments aren't the best approach.

Comment: The funny thing is, that this benchmark shows that creating the hash table _in every step iteration_ is not that expensive operation. both in memory and speed. If converting a particularly large list to hash table is expensive, than it increase the time only 3x. compared to the best solution.

But yes, I agree that _different solutions are useful in different situations_. Let me try something.