# How can I map an integer to an integer?

Tags: r

I need to map an integer to an integer in R.
In python this is the job of a dictionary

```
>>> a = { 4: 1, 5: 2, 6:3 }
>>> a[5]
2
```

but no such thing exists in R. A vector does not work:

```
 a<- c(1,2,3)
> a
[1] 1 2 3
> names(a) <- c(5,6,7)
> a
5 6 7 
1 2 3 
> a[[5]]
Error in a[[5]] : subscript out of bounds
```

a list doesn't work either

```
> a<- list(1,2,3)
> a
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

> names(a) <- c(4, 5, 6)
> a
$`4`
[1] 1

$`5`
[1] 2

$`6`
[1] 3

> a[[6]]
Error in a[[6]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: You just called it wrong. Try `a['5']` or `a[['5']]`. This should work in both lists and named vectors

Comment: @sotos That would require that I access it as a string.

Comment: Oh, you need to call it as integer? Then you can't because R will take the integer as the index, not as the name

Comment: @sotos I added a python example. Is there any data structure I can use for this purpose? i'd prefer not to pass through string if possible.

Comment: No but you should be able to hack it. Maybe build a vector of the form `x <- c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3)`, in which case `x[5]` will give you `2`

Comment: @Sotos I can't. I am mapping id numbers to values, and the id numbers can be huge. Unless the vector code does run length encoding I would waste a massive amount of memory

Comment: Then definitely not. Answer below with `hashmap` should suit you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some [dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818970/is-there-a-dictionary-functionality-in-r/44570412#44570412) in R.

I would suggest the `hashmap` package for your case.

```
library(hashmap)
H <- hashmap(c(2, 4, 6), c(99, 999, 9999))
H
##   (numeric) => (numeric)     
## [+2.000000] => [+99.000000]  
## [+4.000000] => [+999.000000] 
## [+6.000000] => [+9999.000000]
H[[4]]
# [1] 999
```

If you want "true" integers:

```
H <- hashmap(c(2L, 4L, 6L), c(99L, 999L, 9999L))
H
## (integer) => (integer)
##       [2] => [99]     
##       [4] => [999]    
##       [6] => [9999]
```

Answer (score 2):

For good performance you use `match`.

```
k<-c(5,6,7)
v<-c(1,2,3)

x<-c(5,5,6)

v[match(x,k)]
```

In fact, if your `v` is just `1:n` it is enough to do

```
match(x, k)
```

as `match` returns the index in the array you are doing lookup in.

Answer (score 1):

In your last example this should work (`string` not `numeric`):

```
a <- list(1,2,3)
names(a) <- c(4, 5, 6)    

a[["6"]]
a[[as.character(6)]]
```

Comment: So the only way is to cast the key number into a string?

Comment: I think that there is no strict solution (object) for this.

Comment: integer comparison is faster than string comparison, and I would have to go back and forth between strings and integers, which is also a performance burden

Answer (score 1):

A less than optimal possible solution would be to assign the integers into position of their integers in a vector:

```
a[c(5:7)]<-1:3
a[6]
> [1] 2
```

A drawback (or benefit, depends on your needs) is that `a[1]` would yield an `NA`