# Replace elements in one vector with elements containing a similar pattern in another vector

Tags: r, string, dataframe, replace

```
name_w_degree <- c("Julie (Dr)", "Helen (MD)", "Faye")

df <- data.frame(name = c("Julie", "Helen", "Faye", "Faye", "Helen"),
                 value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

I would like to replace "Julie" in df with an element which **starts with** "Julie" from vector *name_w_degree* (i.e. Julie (Dr)). Similary, replace "Helen" in df with an element **starting with** "Helen" from *name_w_degree* (i.e. Helen (MD)) and "Faye" in df with an element starting with "Faye" from *name_w_degree*. Keep value column as is.

Is there a way to mutate the values under the name column taking advantage of the **"starting with a corresponding name"** pattern rather than hard code? Thanks in advance.

Expecting the mutated df to be:

| name_w_degree | value |
| --- | --- |
| Julie (Dr) | 1 |
| Helen (MD) | 2 |
| Faye | 3 |
| Faye | 4 |
| Helen (MD) | 5 |

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Is there a dictionary functionality in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818970).

Answer (score 2):

It is quicker to do vectorised replacement rather than than apply a function to every row, particularly as the size of the data increases. As you want to match on the first word, you can use `setNames()` to create a named vector of patterns and replacements. You can then do vectorised replacement with [`stringr::str_replace_all()`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html):

```r
df$name  <- stringr::str_replace_all(df$name, setNames(name_w_degree, gsub("\\s.+", "", name_w_degree)))
df
#         name value
# 1 Julie (Dr)     1
# 2 Helen (MD)     2
# 3       Faye     3
# 4       Faye     4
# 5 Helen (MD)     5
```

### Benchmarks

It doesn't make much difference with small data frames but as they grow this method becomes relatively much quicker than non-vectorised approaches. The performance is similar to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76667730/12545041) by @ThomasIsCoding until around 800k rows, at which point that approach becomes significantly faster than this one. Both are much faster than approaches which are not vectorised (e.g. using `sapply()` or `map()`), presumably because of the overhead of calling a function many times.

[image]

#### Benchmark code

```r
n <- c(1, 10, 100, 1e3, 1e4, 1e5, 1e6)
results <- bench::press(
    n = n,
    {
        # replicate df n times
        big_df <- do.call(rbind, replicate(n, df, simplify = FALSE))

        bench::mark(
            min_iterations = 1,
            max_iterations = 100,
            check = FALSE,
            rowwise = {
                big_df %>%
                    rowwise() %>%
                    mutate(name = name_w_degree[grepl(name, name_w_degree)])
            },
            base_sapply = {
                sapply(big_df$name, function(x) {
                    name_w_degree[which(grepl(x, name_w_degree))]
                })
            },
            purrr_map_chr = {
                big_df %>%
                    mutate(name = map_chr(name, ~ grep(pattern = ., x = name_w_degree, value = TRUE)))
            },
            stringr_replace_all = {
                stringr::str_replace_all(big_df$name, setNames(name_w_degree, gsub("\\s.+", "", name_w_degree)))
            },
            base_transform = {
                transform(big_df, name = name_w_degree[match(name, sub("\\W+.*", "", name_w_degree))])
            }
        )
    }
)
```

#### Code to generate plot

```r
library(ggplot2)
results |>
    transmute(
        expression = attr(expression, "description"),
        n = n * 5,
        median
    ) |>
    ggplot(aes(x = n, y = median, group = expression)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = expression), size = 1) +
    geom_point(aes(color = expression), size = 2) +
    scale_x_log10(n.breaks = length(n)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
        legend.position = "bottom"
    ) +
    labs(
        title = "Comparison of results",
        x = "Number of rows",
        y = "Median time to run (seconds)"
    )
```

Comment: I think your vectorized approach is fast enough, but `setNames` is slower and `gsub` is a bit less efficient than `sub`, so you can see some speed improvement if you use `match` + `sub`. Anyway, impressive benchmarking, +1!

Answer (score 2):

With base R, try `match` + `sub` like below

```
> transform(df, name = name_w_degree[match(name, sub("\\W+.*", "", name_w_degree))])
        name value
1 Julie (Dr)     1
2 Helen (MD)     2
3       Faye     3
4       Faye     4
5 Helen (MD)     5
```

Comment: Nice! I've added it to my benchmarks. It's the fastest approach of the ones posted now.

Comment: What in cast if there is not match?

Comment: @GKi Then we should take additional actions like `coalesce(..., name)`

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(name = name_w_degree[grepl(name, name_w_degree)])

  name       value
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 Julie (Dr)     1
2 Helen (MD)     2
3 Faye           3
4 Faye           4
5 Helen (MD)     5
```

or

```
df$name <- sapply(df$name, function(x) {name_w_degree[grepl(x, name_w_degree)]})
df

        name value
1 Julie (Dr)     1
2 Helen (MD)     2
3       Faye     3
4       Faye     4
5 Helen (MD)     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(name = map_chr(name, ~ grep(pattern = ., x = name_w_degree, value = TRUE)))

        name value
1 Julie (Dr)     1
2 Helen (MD)     2
3       Faye     3
4       Faye     4
5 Helen (MD)     5
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to store the names as a `factor` and change only the levels in case there is a match of the names using `startsWith`.
In case there are e.g. `Helen` and `Helena` those could be written with a space at the end of their name (`Helen` , `Helena`) to distinguish.

```
df$name <- as.factor(df$name)
levels(df$name) <- unlist(lapply(levels(df$name), \(s) {
       i <- match(TRUE, startsWith(name_w_degree, s))
       if(is.na(i)) s
       else name_w_degree[i] } ) )

df
#        name value
#1 Julie (Dr)     1
#2 Helen (MD)     2
#3       Faye     3
#4       Faye     4
#5 Helen (MD)     5
```

Or a variant using `sub`, `fastmatch` and `collapse`.

```
library(fastmatch)
library(collapse)
tt <- qF(df$name)
i <- fmatch(levels(tt), sub(" .*", "", name_w_degree))
j <- which(!is.na(i))
levels(tt)[j] <- name_w_degree[i[j]]
levels(tt)[tt]
#[1] "Julie (Dr)" "Helen (MD)" "Faye"       "Faye"       "Helen (MD)"
```

Or just using `fastmatch`.

```
library(fastmatch)
i <- fmatch(df$name, sub(" .*", "", name_w_degree))
j <- which(!is.na(i))
`[<-`(df$name, j, name_w_degree[i[j]])
#[1] "Julie (Dr)" "Helen (MD)" "Faye"       "Faye"       "Helen (MD)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create your lookup as a named vector, I assume your names list is pretty small, otherwise you have to think of a better solution anyhow as there might be more Helen's all having different degrees. You can also consider a lookup table and join them. But having said that, here how I would do it (credits for the sub code @ThomasIsCoding)

**note** all names must be present in both the degrees as in the data.

```
names(name_w_degree) <- sub("\\W+.*", "", name_w_degree)

df$name <- name_w_degree[df$name]

df

#         name value
# 1 Julie (Dr)     1
# 2 Helen (MD)     2
# 3       Faye     3
# 4       Faye     4
# 5 Helen (MD)     5
```

**data**

```
name_w_degree <- c("Julie (Dr)", "Helen (MD)", "Faye")

df <- data.frame(name = c("Julie", "Helen", "Faye", "Faye", "Helen"),
                 value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Comment: What in cast if there is not match?

Comment: That is a good point, it can only be used when all names are defines (which is in the example, taking note of "Faye" being present too. It also not covers for more Helen's for example, like Helen (MD) and a Helen (Dr) like all other solutions. I add it to the answer that it only works if all names are known.